# Hosting multiple client websites on single hosting account

Tags: web-hosting, domains, web-development, multiple-domains

I'm web designer and I have currently only a few clients for making a website.
I've unlimited hosting account and I want to host their websites in my account without reseller account (actually it is not needed for constness).

Only my client's need is FTP access to their personal directory.

So is it possible to give them separate phpMyAdmin access with this strategy?

As per my knowledge it is done with "addon" domain pointing on my hosting account's directory with cPanel, am I right? Or there is another solution for it without reseller account?

Comment: I wonder how did you do. Did you achieve anything since you asked this question? More than 2 years passed since then.
Additionally, you should accept the answer below if this helped you.

Comment: The edits to your post did [improve its grammar and spelling](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit), and therefore were approved by a moderator. This is a community-based site with content under the Creative Commons, so [improvements](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit) by the community are welcome and encouraged.

Answer (score 4):

Yes it's possible to use unlimited hosting companies to manage your client's websites and still provide them basic FTP, MySQL, and Email access.

Once you have added your clients domain to your account as an addon domain. You can create FTP accounts in your control panel, even if you must use your primary domain to generate the accounts such as client@maindomain.com, you can tell your client to use client@clientsdomain.com as the login and it will still work. Test this to see for yourself.

MySQL you will most likely need to allow remote access. Ask your client for their IP, do a reverse DNS and use the name version such as *.clientISP.com to give remote access. If you specify their exact IP and they are on a DHCP connection and the IP changes it can cause some delays for them. So to avoid that just use a wild card for their IP's reverse DNS domain. This is often different than the ISP's corporate domain so check.

Email you can typically tell them to login to http://mail.clientdomain.com and they'll be able to access their email as well as change their password. You'll probably have to provide them the pop3 and Imap information though once you create their emails.

Comment: can you please be specific in "how to provide phpmyadmin" access to clients ?

Comment: Install it on their domain, so they can access it using their domain and their own MySQL username and password. Otherwise if you only allow access by their IP and or domain they can use any MySQL management application such as Navicat to manage their databases remotely.

Comment: I guess MySQL will only work if client has static IP. Unfortunately not all clients care to have a static IP.